# Can locative "there" be omitted when the location is explicit?

Tags: there-is, locatives, existential-constructions

Is

> In the park is a tree.

grammatical as

> In the park there is a tree.

? Moreover, how about inaccusative verbs like:

> In the park sits a dog.

?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's okay, but I wouldn't say it's idiomatic.

Comment: You don't give an example containing locative _there_.

Comment: The "there" in your example is not locative, but existential, cf "There (existential) is a sheep over there" (locative).

Comment: So as to clarify: "In the park there is a tree." shows a locative and an existential marker, while "In the park is a tree." shows a locative, only. Is it to say that "In the park Ø is a tree." is simply a different syntax for "In the park there is a tree." with the existential category silenced?

Comment: "In the park is a tree" has the preposition phrase "in the park" as a locative complement, and "a tree" as subject. "In the park there is a tree", has the same locative PP, but the subject is the existential "there". Nothing is "silenced", as you put it -- they are just two different constructions where the meaning is the same. The first example has subject-auxiliary inversion and in the second the locative complement is preposed to a position before the subject. The 'basic' versions would be "A tree is in the park" and "There is a tree in the park".

Comment: Anton, you're over-complicating something much more simple.

Could you re-phrase your Question cover what's left, if you first accept that all three examples are wholly acceptable?

Comment: BillJ, thank you. Just as to clarify, by taking "A tree is in the park" and "There is a tree in the park" as a model, are "A tree is there" as well as "There is a tree there" both grammatical?

Comment: Robbie, I guess I wasn't taking inversion into account. I would say I supposed that the absence of "there" was caused by the presence of the locative in the same position.

Comment: You can use this kind of inversion with verbs like "sit" also; the following question is relevant: [Can the subject go at the end of a clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364237)

Comment: Thank you, sumelic. All the inaccusative verbs, I suppose?

Answer (score -3):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prepositional+phrase

The definition of a prepositional phrase seems to preclude its use as the subject of a verb :-

"as an adjective modifying a noun in the sentence, or as an adverb modifying a verb, adjective, or adverb in the sentence".

But, to me, your example, "In the park is a tree" *sounds* quite correct.

Comment: It's not the subject: it's a complement. The subject is still "A tree" (To see this, compare "In the park are many trees".)

Comment: Right. Locative predicates can exchange subject and complement positions around the _be_ auxiliary. But the _there_ of _In the park there is a tree_ is not a locative _there_, but a dummy _there_ inserted by a rule called, with no irony at all, ["_There_-Insertion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20there%20insertion).

Comment: @ John Lawler So the position of the phrase has no bearing on the grammar ? 'In the park is a tree,' is, grammatically, absolutely equivalent to, 'a tree is in the park' ?

Comment: Does it mean that existential "there" can be silenced when a sentence starts with a locative (In the same way as "There[loc] there[exi] is a tree" would sound odd)?